# Apt broken after upgrading python on 14.04 - No module named 'lsb_release'

Tags: apt, python3

I recently needed an updated version of Python3 for a project, so I built it from source; and I believe I made a bit of a mess. All apt based operations now end in an error here:

```
(Reading database ... 320897 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 28, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-prime (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-prime
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I believe the nvidia error is just more of a symptom than a problem. This was discovered when I was trying to add a source and was met with:

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

I'd gladly upgrade this box to 14.10, but all upgrade based commands return the same lsb_release message. Any advice on restoring my package management abilities?

Edit:
Updating with python path info

```
lars@whorus:~/Downloads/Python-3.4.2$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Dec 18 10:36 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 18  2014 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3349512 Mar 22  2014 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 23  2014 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4061272 Apr 11  2014 /usr/bin/python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4061272 Apr 11  2014 /usr/bin/python3.4m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 23  2014 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.4m
```

Comment: You built python3 from source -- at what path? `/usr/bin/python` may be a symlink to a particular version; the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` may be useful.

Comment: Yikes, unreadable output, adding to the original question

Comment: This has nothing to do with nvidia, but with the Python3 program /usr/lib/lsb_release not finding its module (which should be in `/usr/lib/python3/dist_packages`). How did you configure and install python3? You don't seem to have installed over the system Python3 executables.

Comment: (Broken record time.) Use your distributions binary packages whenever possible, people. If necessary, backport.

Comment: Seems to have some similarities with
[Repairing python setup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218911). (?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 has the `lsb_release.py` file installed for Python 2.7 as well and `lsb_release` seems to work under python2.7 as well. You can try this by doing:

```
python2.7 /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

If that works, make a backup of the file `/usr/bin/lsb_release` and change the first line to read:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
```

(you can experiment with the `-Es` options, I would leave them out intially).

Once you can run `apt-get` again, reinstall python3 and it dependencies. You can determine the direct dependencies by using `apt-cache depends python3` and use `apt-rdepends` or `reverse-depends` (both have to be installed) to get dependencies recursively.

Comment: Thank you sir! This was it, the first line was pointed to `#! /usr/bin/python3`. Whorus lives again, apt is upgrading like crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have overwritten the default python to a customized version.

```
head /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

to see what's on the header.  Forcing it to specific python versions as in /usr/bin should solve the issue.

As in my case, if it writes `/usr/bin/python` in `/usr/bin/lsb_release`, change it to

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

o/w, change it to

```
/usr/bin/python3.4
```