# MySQL-Workbench has uninstallable dependencies on POP!_OS

Tags: dependencies, pop-os

I started by installing mysql-server from the offical repos which was no problem. But here was no installation candidate for mysql-workbench in the official repos, so I opted to download the debian package from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

When i tried to install the debian package I was met with this error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mysql-workbench-community: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed

Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable

Depends: libproj19 (>= 7.2.0) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libzip4 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable
```

Someone on reddit then recommended that I do this

```
wget -O /tmp/mysql-apt-config.deb https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb

sudo apt install /tmp/mysql-apt-config.deb

sudo apt update

sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-workbench-community gnome-keyring
```

Which left me here

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-workbench-community : Depends: libproj15 (>= 6.3.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

You can find a reddit-thread for my issue [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/nstijv/mysql_workbench/)

Comment: standard comment when I read this: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

Comment: I bet this is what happened without me realizing it. any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Backup your database if you have any to stay on the safe side, and remove all explicitly added "offending" packages. mysql-server mysql-workbench-community mysql-apt-config. Remove offending external repositories. Then fix what's remaining by adapting this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218911/repairing-python-setup/218955#218955 . Once you're back to having only Pop OS software, you're fine (and without mysql-workbench).  I don't know what to write instead of "Ubuntu" to adapt it

Comment: Well, it wouldn't seem that this is the problem actually.... There is already a file for the POP!_OS repositories set up with pin-priority: 1001

Comment: That just means there's nothing left to fix as last step.

Comment: I'm not following

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126115/discussion-between-native-coder-and-a-b).

Comment: `mysql-workbench-community` is supposed to fail silently if `libproj` is not installed (check the startup script), but the latest version declares a hard dependency even though the startup script hasn't been changed.  So if your system can't provide `libproj`, you can't install Workbench now.  Same on RHEL8, on CentOS, on Ubuntu.